# Bitmask - Left shift overflow

Tags: c, macros, bitmask

**Problem:**
I want to generate a Bit mask (uint32_t) based on a given length.
Following result should be achieved:

```
BIT_MASK(3) =  0x00..0111 
BIT_MASK(32) = 0x111..111
```

The code given below is working for every length smaller than 32. If the length is 32, the left shift count is larger than the type width (overflow).

```
#define BIT(n)                  ( 1<<(n) )
#define BIT_MASK(len)           ( BIT(len)-1 )

uint32_t length;
uint32_t mask = BIT_MASK(length);
```

**Question:**
Is there any other efficient macro solution to generate a Bit mask, which is not including an additional if/else or typecast to avoid that error.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much it, but you need to change the literal `1` to `1UL`. Otherwise you are restricted to the range of `int`, which is likely 31 bits instead of 32.

```
#define BIT_MASK32(n) ( (1UL<<(n)) - 1UL )
```

Where `n` must be in the range of 0 to 31 to fit a `uint32_t`. To safe guard against overflow, you could make it `(n)%32`, though that will make the macro slower if `n` is a run-time value rather than an integer constant.